# Not getting Google API places classes

Tags: java, android, google-api, google-places-api

I have my manifest with these dependencies:

```
    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')


    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.1.0'
    compile 'biz.kasual:materialnumberpicker:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.3'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.5'
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.2.1'
    compile 'com.synnapps:carouselview:0.0.9'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:actionitembadge:3.2.5@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:iconics-core:2.6.0@aar'
    compile 'com.appsflyer:af-android-sdk:4.+@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    apt 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.5'
}
```

when i do `import com.google.android.gms.location.places`

i'm not getting the classes

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompleteFilter;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompletePrediction;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompletePredictionBuffer;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Places;
```

i was doing a tutorial for the AutocompleteView with this API but they use the version 8.4.0, and when i use the one i'm using it doesn't appear as a suggestion. I'm on Android Studio right now.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/package-summary#classes
these are the classes for the api

Answer (score 0):

You also need

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.4.0'
```

See [Set Up Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)